# Is there any way to change lightning-helptext icon color in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, helptext

here in my component I have 4 lightning helptext:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-helptext/example

And my task is to change their icon colors to blue/yellow/green/red.
I only got the colors red and yellow using icon-variant="warning" and icon-variant="error". But icon-variant brand or success does not work.
Also I've tried using CSS but still no success... is there any way to do it?

Comment: To apply custom styling, use the `:host` selector or define a custom class using the class attribute. `lightning-helptext` contains the same customizable elements as lightning-button-icon for the button icon, which supports `--sds-c-button-*` custom properties. See the `lightning-button-icon` documentation.

Comment: Looks like is not possible to achieve green "success" icon color without custom code/component. [Here](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/issues/678) we can see that there is a ticket on the specific team's roadmap to address icon colors across components, however that is not in place right now. Styling Hooks are in preview (not accessible in production orgs) so I belive that only possible way will be custom code/component.

Answer (score -1):

```css
lwc-colorTextIconDefault: red !important;
```

You can use this.